# Use active mode FTP instead of passive mode during git-clone?

Tags: git, curl, ftp, git-clone

I have a GIT repository on a remote server that I want to access through FTP. For some unfortunate reason the server only allows active mode FTP instead of passive mode. i.e. If I use curl (same client used by `git clone`) to download a file directly, the following command works:

```
curl -P - ftp://user:pass@server/file
```

But taking the `-P -` out will cause curl to hang until time-out.

The problem is I can't figure out how to tell `git clone` to use active mode for FTP. When I set `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and did a `git clone ftp://user:pass@server/repo`, I noticed that it is sending `PASV` instead of `PORT` and hangs just like curl without the `-P -` switch. How do I tell it to do otherwise? I read a bit about the `_netrc` file but couldn't find an example to set up active mode through it.

For anyone curious, here are the verbose curl outputs from `git clone` (pretty much the same as running `curl` without specifying the `-P -` option.)

```
* About to connect() to server.com port 21 (#0)
*   Trying {server ip}... * 0x98d548 is at send pipe head!
* Connected to server.com ({server ip}) port 21 (#0)
< 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> USER User
< 331 Password required for User.
> PASS {pass}
< 230 User User logged in.
> PWD
< 257 "/User" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/User'
> CWD repo.git
< 250 CWD command successful.
> CWD info
< 250 CWD command successful.
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 500 'EPSV': command not understood
* disabling EPSV usage
> PASV
< 227 Entering Passive Mode ({server ip},10,137).
*   Trying {server ip}... * Connecting to {server ip} ({server ip}) port 2697
/* server hangs from here until time-out */
```

With the `-P -` option specified for curl, `PORT` command will be used in place of `PASV`, so starting from the `EPSV` line the following commands will be sent instead to the server:

```
> EPRT |1|{client ip}|13375|
< 500 'EPRT |1|{client public ip}|36093|': command not understood
* disabling EPRT usage
> PORT {client ip},52,64
< 200 PORT command successful.
* Connect data stream actively
> TYPE I
< 200 Type set to I.
> SIZE file
< 213 213
> RETR file
< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file(213 bytes).
/* and the file just downloads from here. */
```

My configuration: msysgit, MS-FTP server.

Comment: does your server support EPSV mode?

Comment: No it does not. `EPSV` is actually the first command `git clone` tried before falling back to `PASV`.

Comment: do you have any idea of why it hangs with git and not with `curl -P`?

Comment: I added the verbose outputs from `curl -P` and git. I suspect the server has policies blocking ports that `PASV` tries to open, thus only active mode works.

Comment: Not perfect, but just use curl to download the git dir and if necessary clone locally afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git actually [deprecated FTP](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#URLS), probably because of such difficulties:

> Git supports ssh, git, http, and https protocols (in addition, ftp,
>   and ftps can be used for fetching and rsync can be used for fetching
>   and pushing, but these are inefficient and deprecated; do not use
>   them).

Your best bet would be to rsync the remote repo from the FTP server to a local bare clone, and re-clone it to a working copy.

Comment: Thanks very much! I actually managed to find an open port to enable PASV mode on the server. But from reading this, the best answer is probably indeed "try not to use FTP". I will look into other options.